# How to start a python program using java (Runtime.getRuntime().exec())

Tags: python, java

I am writing a program that requires the starting of a python script before the rest of the java code runs. However, I cannot find a solution to my issues. I would appreciate if someone could suggest a solution to the problem I am facing.

Code (I need help on the part under the comment "start python"):

```
import java.io.IOException;

//makes it easier for user to
//select game/start python
public class gameselect {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        //start python
        try {
            String cmd = "python ngramcount.py";
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            process.getInputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        //select game
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
            game1 g = new game1();
            game2 f = new game2();
            int choice = 0;
            System.out.println("Welcome to TranslateGame!");
            System.out.println("Type 1 for game1 (words) or 2 for game2 (phrases)");
            while (choice != 1 && choice != 2) {
                choice = in.nextInt();
                if (choice != 1 && choice != 2) {
                    System.out.println("No game associated with that number.");
                }
            }
            if (choice == 1) {
                g.game1();
            }
            else if (choice == 2) {
                f.game2();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `Exception` say?

Comment: Runtime does not execute in the context of a shell, probably you need to specify the correct current directory when creating the process, and provide the absolute path to the python executable.

Comment: @JimGarrison How exactly would I go about that? I'm not very experienced in working with this kind of thing. Do you have any links to where I could read more?

Comment: Start by reading the Javadocs.  You probably should use the newer `ProcessBuilder` class. The example in the `ProcessBuilder` Javadoc should help.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks for the help. Will definitely check out ProcessBuilder and Javadoc.

Comment: Depending on the Python and script config on the machine, you may need one of "ngramcount.py" or  `{"python","ngramcount.py"}` either of which may also need params prefixed by full pathname to the correct location. You need to add more details to your question including the exception, and it doesn't give us a clue as to how you want to use the python program in the following Java code.

Comment: @DuncG I resolved my issue. I had to use ProcessBuilder instead of Process.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that you might be able to get to work. I also commented it and provided some reference links to help you understand what the code is doing.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // I'm using the absolute path for my example.
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\yourname\\Desktop\\testing.py";

    // Creates a ProcessBuilder
    // doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", fileName);

    pb.redirectErrorStream(true); // redirect error stream to a standard output stream
    Process process = pb.start(); // Used to start the process

    // Reads the output stream of the process.
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line; // this will be used to read the output line by line. Helpful in troubleshooting.
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }



}
```